# redirecting input in c++

Tags: c++, redirect

i was told that to redirect from standard input to file i need to do the following:

```
static std::ifstream inF("inpur.txt");
std::cin.rdbuf(inF.rdbuf());
```

and every call to std::cin will be redirected to input.txt.
but my question is: do i need to open inF? and if i do, where do i need to do this?

Comment: Please clarify: do you need to redirect FROM standard input to an OUTPUT file, or redirect standard input FROM an INPUT file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the beauty. You already did so while declaring the object and passing the string to the explicit constructor of ifstream.

The file is opened in TEXT mode.

Refer [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Answer (score 4):

You opened it by calling it with the string constructor.

Comment: then why the inF.is_open() returning false?

Comment: Post the actual code. And `inpur.txt` looks like a mis-spelling.

Comment: @or.nomore: That can mean two things: Either the file could not be opened (e.g. doesn't exist), or you ran into the static initialization order fiasco (see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

Comment: oh.. sure! that the problem, i didn't create it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as-is fine. Do make a backup though of the original `cin.rdbuf` -- you may need to reset it in case of an error.